# Custom data sorting in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, database, sorting, gridview

Is there a way I can do some custom data sorting in GridView ? I mean for example there is a great in which there are several project entries, each project has a status like Hold, Complete, Awaiting Feedback, Working and so on... now I would like to sort according to status column but not alphabetically instead I would like to arrange them in custom fashion like Hold then Awaiting Feedback then Working and then complete. Is it possible somehow, if so please provide an example so I can understand.

There is one idea that comes in my mind, that I should create a numeric column in table that contains statuses and assign numbers like 1,2 and 3... in order I like to have and then bind that column in grid, keep it invisible and sort according to it but if there is another simpler way in which I dont have to modify database table I would like to try that first.

Thanks.

Comment: What format is your data in? A DataSet/DataTable or a Collection of something?

Comment: Well I don't quiet understand what you mean Doozer, I am fairly new in ASP.net, if you mean what method I used to bind data to gridview then I used SqlDataSource in which I wrote my own query to get data from sql database table.

Comment: Your most likely and quickest solution then is the one you provided yourself, of handling it with a hidden sort on the statuses. DataView by themselves won't allow a custom sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my own idea and implemented a hidden column named as priority and assigned it numeric values in order, for example since "Hold" has highest priority then it should get numeric value of 1 after that Awaiting Feedback should get 2 and so on... Instead of binding that column with gridview and keeping it hidden I used ORDER BY in sql data source.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a numeric value to each of your possible Status (Hold = 1, Awaiting = 2, etc) and use that numeric value as the Sort Expression property of the GridView column.

Hope this helps!